# Same index data but different store size in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am evaluating the necessary storage size required by ElasticSearch. However, I find that the store size varies every time while indexing the same set of data.

For example, the size of the data I used is 35mb. The indexing ran for several times, and the result store sizes are between 76mb ~ 85mb, not a fixed number (not repeatable?)

Can someone explain this? Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you've inserted all of your data, have you tried doing an optimze (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-optimize.html) to bring the number of segments down to 1?

Basically the time at which it does the Lucene segment merges causes the differences in sizes you are seeing.  They are not deterministic because once the merge kicks off, the amount of data you insert before the merge completes affects the size of the remaining segments.  You can read a little more about the segment merges here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-merge.html and here: [Understanding Segments in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426441/basics-about-segments-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation and the references:)

Comment: Looks like the first link is broken - is this no longer valid for latest version? (6.5)