# ElasticSearch: creating new inverted-index after every update

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I've stucked with one question in my understanding of ElasticSearch indexing process. I've already read [this article](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html#inverted-index), which says, that inverted-index stores all tokens of all documents and it is immutable. So, to update it we must remove it  and reindexing all data to have all document searchable.

But I've read about partial updating the documents (automaticaly marking them to "deleted" and inserting+indexing new one). But in those article where no mention about reindexing all previous data.

So, I do not understand properly next: when I update the document (text document with 100 000 words) and already have in storage some other indexed document - is it true that I will have on every UPDATE or INSERT operation reindexing process of all my documents?

Basicly I rely on default ElasticSearch settings (5 primary shards with one replica per shard and 2 nodes in cluster)

Comment: and I also suggest not to ask more then one question in a post

Answer (score 1):

You can just have a document updated (that is reindexed, which is basically the same as removing from index and adding it again), see: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/update-doc.html This will take care of the whole index, so you won't need to reindex every other document.

I'm not sure what you mean by "save" operation, you may want to clarify it with an example.

As of the time required to update a document of 100K words, I suggest you to try it out.

Comment: Yes, I've read this. What means 'This will take care of the whole index'? If I INSERT or UPDATE the document, the inverted-index storage became out-of-date, so, all documents in same index should be reindexed, if I understand right... But how the updates can be available in 1 second (I've read this in the guide) if I have a huge amount of document in storage?

Comment: It means the updated document will be first removed from the index and then added again, hence the inverted-index will be up-to-date after the update. How can an update take only 1 sec? That is a deeper question, suffice to say here that Lucene devs are smart people, I encourage to study the [indexing implementation](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/index/).

Comment: Thanks! Couple of minutes ago I've found the post that helped me to understand meaning of 'shards segments'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426441/basics-about-segments-in-elasticsearch Every time we updating the document it is indexed on a new segment (new inverted-index) and after some time those indexed are merged in background